# How to add different vpc instances(node) to existing eks vpc ( both vpc are different)

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-vpc, amazon-eks

i have a aws eks cluster with in the dev vpc now i have few ec2 instance in the test-vpc so now i need add the add test-vpc instance to the existing existing cluster. can we do. ?

FYI VPC peering i have done as well and peering also working

Answer (score 0):

An Amazon EKS cluster is provisioned in a single [VPC](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/eks-networking.html).

If you have a dev-VPC and a test-VPC, you need to use two different EKS clusters.

Comment: try vpc -peering

Comment: vpc peering already done it's working also but node is not able to attach to the different eks cluster

Comment: the nodes in the cluster must be in the same VPC